# Set up my payment solution in sandbox

Tags: sandbox, paypal-sandbox

Here's the thing:

I have a business sandbox account created, then after opening the Sandbox PayPal site and logging in (of course, using the sandbox account credentials), when I click on "My Business Setup" and then "product selection page" (see picture), it redirects me to the non-sandbox PayPal account.

So, I cannot add a product to my sandbox account...

[image]
Well, obviously that looks like a PayPal sandbox bug.

What I wanna do is just add a business solution "Website Payments Pro" and create recurring payments.

Does anyone know another way to add that business solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't enable Website Payments Pro that way. Granted, we should fix that.
You can enable Webiste Payments Pro via https://developer.paypal.com > Applications > Sandbox accounts > Click 'Profile' followed by 'Products'.

In here you can enable Website Payments Pro.

[image: PayPal Sandbox Manager - Enable Pro]